# What is the lifetime of gitlab $CI_JOB_TOKEN

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab, gitlab-ci

Given this login:
`docker login -u gitlab-ci-token -p $CI_JOB_TOKEN registry.example.com`

What is the lifetime of the login?  Specifically for use with kubernetes deployments. Will kubernetes need an actual gitlab user created for it to restart nodes and re-pull images?

Comment: This is a setting "admin settings -> Authorization token duration (minutes)".

Comment: I should be clear, I'm using gitlab.com    not self-hosted gitlab.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the setting on gitlab.com is, but it looks like the default token duration is 5 minutes, but you can [increase the token duration](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/packages/container_registry.html#increase-token-duration):

> In GitLab, tokens for the container registry expire every five minutes. To increase the token duration:
>
> 1. On the left sidebar, at the bottom, select Admin Area.
> 2. Select Settings > CI/CD.
> 3. Expand Container Registry.
> 4. For the Authorization token duration (minutes), update the value.
> 5. Select Save changes.